# How to display div next to table row?

Tags: jquery, css, coldfusion

I have a table that is displaying data from a query.

Right now when i click on the #emp_namefirst# it shows me the #emp_cell# but it display it
on the bottom of the table.

How can i display the div next to the table row that i click on the #emp_namefirst#?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a').click(function () {
         //var StateName = $(this).prop("detail");
            var StateName = $(this).attr("detail");   
            $('#maintext').show();
            $('#output').html(StateName);

        });

    });
</script>
     <table   class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve"    >
      <thead><th >Name</th><th >Department</th></thead>

        <tbody>
        <cfloop query="Corporate"  >
        <cfoutput>
        <tr>

        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
        <td >#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>

        </tbody>

 </table>
 <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: P.S you're missing `<tr>` tags  in `<thead>`

Comment: yes sorry i actually took some code out on the table to make it smaller

Comment: What is the result you are getting now? Can you demonstrate with a jsFiddle?

Comment: Ok, so when I click `emp_namefirst` cell... where should appear the `detail` value? in the cell where you have `dept_name` or you want to create a floating DIV or append another cell? It's not entirely clear what you expect as a result.

Comment: You're also missing `</span>` and `</a>`. not sure about ColdFusion, but instead of using invalid `detail` attributes (if invalid in cf) use `data-detail`

Comment: @roko i want to display it next to the table row, like a new collumn

Comment: When asking a client-side question, it's always helpful to take sometime to extract a client-side markup sample; most of the time the server-side code (like ColdFusion in your case) just gets in the way and does not add value to the question.

Comment: @PeterKA All too true. It makes it much easier for others to work with the code too, in cases where you might have something like `<td id="#i#">`, it's a nagging process to go copy the row a few times and replace variables with meaningful values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup a demonstration fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/43dmvvto/3/

I changed your links to have the class "datalink" so I could reference that in Jquery so that not every link triggered it.

For the example, I also copied your data rows, so you could see it in action.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a.datalink').click(function () {
            //var StateName = $(this).prop("detail");
            var StateName = $(this).attr("detail");   
            $('#maintext').show();
            $('#output').html(StateName);
            $('#output').css('top',$(this).offset().top);
            $('#output').css('left',($(this).offset().left + parseInt($("#mTable").css('width'))));
            $("#output").css('visibility','visible');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This following should do it. My only concern is that you're duplicating the `id` of the `a` element; use of a `class` would be much better. And I would recommend using a data attribute `data-detail`.  Since a div can only be a child of td inside a table, the code below puts your contents in the div and then puts the div in a `td` with `colspan="2"` in a new `tr` below the cell that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var out = $('#output'),
        tr = $('<tr/>'),
        td = $('<td/>',{colspan:2});
    $('a.showdata').click(function () {
        var StateName = $(this).data("detail");   
        $('#maintext').show();
        out.html( StateName ).parent().is('td') || tr.html( td.html( out ) );
        $(this).closest('tr').after( tr );
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         var out = $('#output'),
             tr = $('<tr/>'),
             td = $('<td/>',{colspan:2});
         $('a.showdata').click(function () {
            var StateName = $(this).data("detail");   
            $('#maintext').show();
            out.html( StateName ).parent().is('td') || tr.html( td.html( out ) );
            $(this).closest('tr').after( tr );
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table   class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve"    >
      <thead><tr><th >Name</th><th >Department</th></tr></thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  class="showdata"  data-detail="Cell: 999-900-9000">John</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  class="showdata"  data-detail="Cell: 999-900-9111">Jane</td>
        <td>Payroll</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  class="showdata"  data-detail="Cell: 999-900-9222">James</td>
        <td>Operations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  class="showdata"  data-detail="Cell: 999-900-9333">Mary</td>
        <td>Legal</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

 </table>
 <div id="output"></div>
```